# Partition Magic error when resizing partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have a problem with my E: partition. I installed a Partition Magic 8.0 to resize it, and when I started it, Partition Magic gave some errors, and changed drive letter from `E:` to `*:`.

I can't see that partition anymore in Windows Explorer. I have important data on my drive.

Comment: Not an answer, & too late now, but I would suggest NOT using (Norton/Symantec) Partition Magic for anything.  It has not been updated in ages.  It will not be updated.  Technologies have changed.  Partition Magic has remained static (since say 2004 or so).  There are other partition tools out there - free too, that are updated regularly.  (And you should backup first, regardless.)

Comment: Ok, i have give up PM 8.0.You said some freeware,would u recommend any better? About the backup issue, how about windows 7 build-in backup utility? Is it more convenient than the freeware?

Comment: Windows backup will make an image of your hard drive, which means it will create an exact copy of your data and settings when you restore. As for the data on the "missing" partition, I'd look into some recovery software to see if the data can be rebuilt. If all that's damaged is the partition map, the data should still be there.

Answer (score 1):

On your desktop, right-click on `My Computer`, click `Manage`, and go to the `Disk Management` section (I'm assuming you're on Windows XP).

When there, see if your drive is still there. If it is, try to assign it a drive letter using `Change Drive Letter and Paths` option.

Comment: Thx for ur help! Well, i have tried that and it is not working any more.

Comment: I've added a comment to your question which might help.

Comment: Many thx for your comment. I have use EAASEUS partition master solved the problem! Fortunately I don't lose any data and i can access my partitions normally.Thank God!

Comment: Good to hear. Please put your solution in its own answer, and then accept it, so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using Paragon Partition Manager (Windwos) or GParted (Linux).
For linux I mean boot into linux live and do other things .